# Fill area in Incanter

Tags: charts, clojure, incanter

Is it possible to create a filled area in a chart using Incanter (Clojure)? I cannot find anything about this in the manual.

For instance, say I have the following function to create a simple scatter plot:

```
   (defn daycurve-test []
      (doto (scatter-plot (range 0 20) (range 0 20))
        (add-polygon [[0 0] [0 10] [10 10] [10 0]])
        view))
```

This will draw a scatter plot and a black rectangle on the screen. Is there a way to fill this rectangle using e.g. red?